# KaptExecution after migrating to Hilt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I add Hilt dependencies (2.37) to my project. After migrating to hilt from dagger2, I got this error when tried to run the project:

```
Execution failed for task 'app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

These are my library versions:

Hilt: 2.37

Kotlin: 1.5.20 (Java 8)

Room: 2.3.0

Comment: What Java compiler version are you using? We ran into this yesterday with an engineer who wound up with Java 16 as the JDK, and Java 16 has issues with `kapt`, apparently.

Comment: @CommonsWare
I'm using java 8

Comment: Try running a command-line build with `--stacktrace`, and see if the full stack trace gives you more to go on.

Comment: @CommonsWare
I did it before and there was no clue

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Kotlin version to "1.4.30".

If reverting Kotlin version doesn't works try to reverting the libraries to previous versions which you might have recently updated.

Also make sure your libraries are using kapt instead of annotationProcessor.

Plugins Required:

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
   id 'kotlin-android'
   id 'kotlin-kapt'
   id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
   id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```